# Loading static files on a Tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, directory

Having an issue which I see others have had with loading static files (e.g html) on a Tomcat server. Following a [guide on accessing local files from a tomcat server](http://teknosrc.com/access-local-files-static-content-images-videos-media-files-outside-web-application-system-apache-tomcat-server/), I have added `<Context docBase="F:/Sprint000" path="/static" />` to the `server.xml` file. I keep getting a 404 error. I'm assuming the root folder is `webapps'?

Any ideas?

Directory:`webapps/Sprint000/index.htm`

**Server.xml**

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>

      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">

        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />

       <Context docBase="/Sprint000" path="/static" />  
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
```

Comment: try changing `docBase=...` to the absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for file `context.xml`, edit it become to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context reloadable="true">
    <Resources>
        <PreResources
            base="F://Sprint000"
            className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet"
            webAppMount="/static" />
    </Resources>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
        allow=".*" />
</Context>
```

Comment: Still 404 error, and the URL I entered is `http://localhost:8080/static/index.htm`. Correct?

Comment: Do you revert `server.xml` like original status? (before config by `context.xml`)

Comment: Reverted back to original `server.xml` file, and made the changes to `context.xml`. Still 404 error

Comment: Check case: `http://localhost:8080/webapp_name/static/index.htm`. My solution worked in production environment (critical-mission application, Apache Tomcat 8). I confidence on my solution.

Comment: Tried but no success. I'll keep trying and hopefully I won't end up smashing my computer.  Thank you for your time and help!